# XSL not applying templates correctly

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Good morning!

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Relatorio.xsl"?>
<relatório id="LPROG" xmlns="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog Relatorio.xsd">
    <páginaRosto>
        <tema>oRolhas</tema>

        <!--Bunch of other fields-->

    </páginaRosto>

    <!--Bunch of other fields-->

</relatório>
```

The XML is correctly formed and validated using the given XSD.

After applying this simple .xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1 align="center">Relatório Trabalho</h1>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="relatório/páginaRosto"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="páginaRosto">
        <h1>Page</h1>
        <h2>Tema:
            <xsl:value-of select="tema"/>
        </h2>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body><h1 align="center">Relatório Trabalho</h1></body>
</html>
```

It is not "printing" the "páginaRosto" template, and I can't figure out why.
Is there any problem with my XPath expressions or even with the XML file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @michael.hor257k so the OP should then remove the root node !?

Comment: @wero I suggest you read the *answer*, not the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml defines a default namespace `xmlns="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"`

To match elements in the default namespace the XPath expression must use the same namespace (but must define a non empty prefix):

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
    xmlns:p="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog"      
    select="p:relatório/p:páginaRosto"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
<relatório id="LPROG" xmlns:lp="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog" 
    ...
</relatório>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:apply-templates xmlns:lp="http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/lprog" select="relatório/páginaRosto"/>
```

Result:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 align="center">Relatório Trabalho</h1>
      <h1>Page</h1>
      <h2>Tema:
            oRolhas</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```